# Flask set default security field for spectree validate decorators

Tags: flask, swagger

I just finished adding security to my spectree validate decorator for my flask app:

```
@rest.post("/url")
@spectree.validate(json=InputSchema, security=[{"apiKey": "X-API-KEY"}, {"Source": "Authorization"}])
def ep_document(json: InputSchema):
    ...
```

Is there a way to set this as a default security so that I don't have to add this field to all my spectree decorators?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's possible to do this config directly in spectree config:

```
spectree = SpecTree(
    "flask",
    ...
    security={"x_api_key": "X-API-KEY", "authorization": "Authorization"},
    security_schemes=[
        SecurityScheme(
            name="x_api_key",
            data=SecuritySchemeData(
                **{
                    "type": "apiKey",
                    "name": "X-API-KEY",
                    "in": "header",
                    "scheme": "basic",
                }
            ),
        ),
        SecurityScheme(
            name="authorization",
            data=SecuritySchemeData(
                **{
                    "type": "apiKey",
                    "name": "Authorization",
                    "in": "header",
                    "scheme": "basic",
                }
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
```